# AES Encryption algorithms and padding scheme

Tags: java, encryption, sonarqube, aes, padding

Hello currently i have to do an AES encription and send it to an external SW but i am having trouble with the sonarqube.

this is the relevant part of my current code:

```
String encriptedPad = afegir0Multiple8(Hex.encodeHexString(encriptar.getBytes()));
    String cadenaAmb0 = afegir0Multiple8(encriptar);  //Creem un cadena amb la longitut que necessitem
    byte[] cadenaRes = cadenaAmb0.getBytes();  //Cadena resultant per encriptar
    //Clau
    byte[] hexclaub = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(claveCifradoRedsa);
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(ArrayUtils.addAll(hexclaub,ArrayUtils.subarray(hexclaub,0,8)), "AES");

    //Vector Init
    String v = vectorInicial;
    IvParameterSpec ivectorSpecv = new IvParameterSpec(v.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    
    //Encriptem
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivectorSpecv);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(cadenaRes);
```

Is a little spaguetti cause it´s recyclated for an old code (TripleDES) sorry for that.
But we can get the gist of it that`s that we are using an AES configuration with AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING

the thing is that our sonarqube is getting this output when i send this code:

[image]

Could someone explain me a little about oracle padding attacks and if there is some impact using the instance recommended by sonar? I am quite lost with encryption

pd: The SW has accepted to change the configuration but i would like to understand why i have to use one specific configuration above others

thanks

Comment: Regarding padding oracle attacks you can find enough information on the web, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack). sonarqube refers to AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING, i.e. CBC mode in combination with PKCS#5 (or PKCS#7) padding, which allows such an attack as described in the article, and recommends a mode that doesn't require padding, e.g. GCM. GCM is an authenticated encryption algorithm, i.e. provides not only confidentiality but also authenticity/integrity (CBC provides only confidentiality). The latter only for completeness, sonarqube does not mention this explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Topaco i will look into GCM encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the question is already solved thanks to @Topaco in the comments below. I will update my code here in order to make this question answered.

My current Code looks like this:

```
@Override
public Map execute(Map in) throws Exception {
    log.info("********** CIFRADO AES ACTION ****************");
    Map params = (Map) in.get("request_params");
    Map resultado = new HashMap();
    resultado.put("clave", encriptarAES((String) in.get("encriptar"),(String) in.get("claveCifrado"),(String) in.get("vectorInicial")));
    return resultado;
}

private String encriptarAES(String encriptar, String claveCifradoRedsa, String vectorInicial) throws Exception {
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(claveCifradoRedsa.getBytes(), "AES");
    key =  new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");
    //Encriptem
    GCMParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, vectorInicial.getBytes());

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(instance);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParameterSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(encriptar.getBytes());      
    String codificado64 = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
    log.info(encriptar);
    log.info(codificado64);
    log.info("************************ FIN CIFRADO AES ACTION ***********************");
    return codificado64;
}
```

I think it a pretty clean example of AES encryption, hope it´s useful to someone